# Send Welcome mail to new user ( flutter web )

Tags: firebase, function, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, cloud

I want to send user a welcome mail at the time of signup.
Frontend Flutter (web).
backend Firebase.
Please Help.
Thanks

Comment: this question was already asked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58704204/15941153

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need you use Firebase Cloud Functions with [authentication triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events) this way:

```
exports.sendWelcomeEmail = functions.auth.user().onCreate(user => {
    const newUser = user;
    
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(transport[, defaults])

    var message = {
      from: "sender@server.com",
      to: "receiver@sender.com",
      subject: "Message title",
      text: "Plaintext version of the message",
      html: "<p>HTML version of the message</p>"
    };

    transporter.sendMail(message)
    return null
});
```

I've used Nodemailer here but you could use any email service. Nodemailer is free and you can read more about it [here](https://nodemailer.com).

Alternatively you can use Firebase's [send email extension](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-send-email) which also requires Firestore.

Comment: Hi,i have installed nodemailer using "npm install nodemailer". However, 'nodemailer' is never recognized. How to import it to use in the dart file?? thanks